# getting an err like: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: angularjs

Am new to angular js....i wrote simple example using http post call..
but it throws an error like

Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=MyApp&p1=Error%3A%2…tps%3A%2F%2Ftestvendor.planotest.com%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A315)

My js code is given below..

```
$(function () {

    var ang = angular.module('MyApp', []);

    MyApp.controller('tagReports', function ($scope) {
        $scope.CustomerTagID = _TagID;
        $scope.listOfTags = [];
        $scope.tagList = [];

        $scope.LoadCustomerDetails = function () {

            $http({ method: " post", url: "/LeadManagement/Customer/GetCustomerDetailsListByTag/" + viewModel.CustomerTagID(), cache: $templateCache }).
            success(function (data) {
            }).
            error(function (data, status) {
            });

        };
    });
});
```

thank you

Comment: just some hints:  MyApp.controller should be ang.controller in your example; you are using $templateCache but did not require it - e.g. function($scope, $templateCache); it looks a litle bit odd using the $templateCache directly and also using a post request for that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to use IIFE for angualarjs with jQuery. So I have fixed the code as below

```
(function ($) {

var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);

MyApp.controller('tagReports', function ($scope, $http, $templateCache) {

    $scope.CustomerTagID = _TagID;
    $scope.listOfTags = [];
    $scope.tagList = [];

    $scope.LoadCustomerDetails = function () {

        $http({ method: " post", url: "/LeadManagement/Customer/GetCustomerDetailsListByTag/" + viewModel.CustomerTagID(), cache: $templateCache }).
        success(function (data) {
        }).
        error(function (data, status) {
        });
    };
});
})(jQuery);
```

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject $http as a dependency into your controller, like that:

```
MyApp.controller('tagReports', function ($scope, $http) {});
```